# Sharing a single session within two different Web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, session, sharing

I have been using two different web application, one has been developed in **Asp.net** and other which i am developing right now is in **AngularJS**(which is stand alone).

so now my question is, Is it possible to access a session of **ASP.net** app to **Angularjs** App?

if it is possible to do so then please suggest me how can i achieve it?

Thanks, Help will be appreciated.

Comment: i do have same issue, and looking for the solution since last 2 days.

Comment: Have you maybe seen this post, http://chsakell.com/2015/03/07/angularjs-feat-web-api-enable-session-state/ maybe the concept can be manipulated for your use?

Comment: @LouisLewis thanks, let me take a look on that

Comment: What about using a `JSONP` (to get around `CORS` issue)? You could make HTTP handler (or web service) to handle jsonp requests - inside your asp.net application and then just call it from `AngularJS` using `$http.jsonp`. Based on passed key argument you would return `session` value.

Comment: @IvanSivak i think that would be a great deal.

Comment: @Mr.Cool What server side technology are you using for AngualrJs? Web API?

Comment: @Win i am using it through node-mssql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not possible to access the session as it saved on the application pool on your IIS.

I would suggest two workarounds:

1. add REST end point which get the session KEY and retrieve the VALUE, then use this service with your angular.js code to get the session values.
2. refactor your asp.net code to work with cookies instead of session and then you could access this data.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think ASP.NET change the cookie name every start.

Comment: I agree with option 1. Making a call to the server-side code is the only practical option from client-side code. Have an ednpoint (MVC controller or WebApi controller) that exposes a method which will return values from session.

Comment: @stav mizrahi ur ans is helpful but doen't solved my Issue completely. Upvoted Answer.